# Need to generate rows with missing data in a large dataset - SQL

Tags: sql-server

We are comparing values between months over multiple years. As time moves on the number of years and months in the dataset increases. We are only interested in months where there were values for every year, i.e. a full set.

Consider the following example for 1 month (1) over 3 years (1,2,3) and two activities (101, 102)

Dataset:

```
Activity   Month    year    Count
-------    ----    ------   ------
101        1        1        2
101        1        2        3
101        1        3        1
102        1        1        1       
102        1        2        1
```

In the example above  only activity 101 will come into consideration as it satisfies the condition that there must be a count for the activity for month 1 IN year 1, 2 and 3.

Activity 102 doesn't qualify for further analysis as it has no record for year 3.

I would like to generate a record with which I can then evaluate this. The record will effectively generate the new record with the missing row (in this case 102, 1, 3 , 0) to complete the dataset

```
Activity   Month    year    Count
-------    ----    ------   ------
102        1        3        0
```

We find the problem difficult as the data keeps in growing, the number of activities keep expanding and it is a combination of activity, year and month that need to be evaluated.

An elegant solution will be appreciated.

Comment: If you create a dataset of all your activities and months/years by use of a `CROSS JOIN`, you can then `LEFT JOIN` to your table and you'll have the data set you need. *Presumably* you have both an `Activity` table, with all your activities, and a Calendar table, with all your months and years that you can use to do that?

Comment: what do you mean by every year? How the system will understand to take only 1,2,3 as compete year ? Is it user input ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I mention in my comment, *presumably* you have both an `Activity` table and some kind of Calendar table with details of your activities and the years in your system. As such you can therefore do a `CROSS JOIN` between these 2 objects and then `LEFT JOIN` to your table to get the data set you want:

```sql
--Create sample objects/data
CREATE TABLE dbo.Activity (Activity int); --Obviously your table has more columns
INSERT INTO dbo.Activity (Activity)
VALUES (101),(102);
GO
CREATE TABLE dbo.Calendar (Year int,
                           Month int);--Likely your table has more columns
INSERT INTO dbo.Calendar (Year, Month)
VALUES(1,1),
      (2,1),
      (3,1);
GO

CREATE TABLE dbo.YourTable (Activity int,
                            Year int,
                            Month int,
                            [Count] int);
INSERT INTO dbo.YourTable (Activity,Month, Year, [Count])
VALUES(101,1,1,2),
      (101,1,2,3),
      (101,1,3,1),
      (102,1,1,1),
      (102,1,2,1);
GO
--Solution
SELECT A.Activity,
       C.Month,
       C.Year,
       ISNULL(YT.[Count],0) AS [Count]
FROM dbo.Activity A
     CROSS JOIN dbo.Calendar C
     LEFT JOIN dbo.YourTable YT ON A.Activity = YT.Activity
                               AND C.[Year] = YT.[Year]
                               AND C.[Month] = YT.[Month]
WHERE C.Month = 1; --not sure if this is needed
```

If you *don't* have an `Activity` and Calendar table (I suggest, however, you should), then you can use subqueries with a `DISTINCT`, but note this will be far from performant with large data sets:

```sql
SELECT A.Activity,
       C.Month,
       C.Year,
       ISNULL(YT.[Count],0) AS [Count]
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT Activity FROM dbo.YourTable) A
     CROSS JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT Year, Month FROM dbo.YourTable) C
     LEFT JOIN dbo.YourTable YT ON A.Activity = YT.Activity
                               AND C.[Year] = YT.[Year]
                               AND C.[Month] = YT.[Month]
WHERE C.Month = 1; --not sure if this is needed
```

Comment: You can use [Itzik's famous tally function](https://sqlperformance.com/2021/01/t-sql-queries/number-series-solutions-1) to generate a calendar on the fly

Comment: Thank you for the solution, works a charm and fit for our purposes